# Jquery CSS switch

Tags: css

I cannot get the switch using the Jquery mobile css to display the whole word 'completed'. I cannot figure out how to expand the width of the slider.

```
<div data-role="page" id="viewtask"
  <div id="task" align="center" style=" width:100%;">
  <label for="flip-complete">Change Completed Status</label>
  <select name="slider" id="flip-complete" data-role="slider">
     <option id="yes" value="off">Completed</option>
     <option id ="no" value="on">Not Completed</option>
  </select>
  <button class="ui-btn"> Finalize Change</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jquery mobile documentation says to simply expand the width, which has not worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. The select option for completed shows the whole word as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa5Fh/).

Comment: Hm, I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2 and it looks nothing like it does in jsfiddle. It is a slider switch toggle and shows half of the word completed

Comment: I changed the mobile css version to 1.4.2 and it still works. Can you create a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: I think this might be his problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9P7cs/

Comment: yes that was the problem @Rickkwa

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
div.ui-slider-switch { width: 10em; }
```

Though you may want to restrict it to a wrapper div so that it doesn't affect all your switches.